# what are the differnt in <req:xxx> and <ns1:xxx> in SOAP request

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, soapui

Can anybody explain the difference between `<req:xxx>` and `<ns1:xxx>` usage in soap request xml schema .?

eg:-

**1st SOAP request XML Schema**

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://olp.bank.com/payement/service/olppaymentmanager/req">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <req:initiatePaymentDetailsReq>
         <olpIdAlias>****</olpIdAlias>
         <merchantId>****</merchantId>
         <merchantRefNum>234324</merchantRefNum>
         <paymentAmount>200</paymentAmount>
         <paymentCurrency>SAR</paymentCurrency>
         <dynamicMerchantLandingURL></dynamicMerchantLandingURL>
         <dynamicMerchantFailureURL></dynamicMerchantFailureURL>
      </req:initiatePaymentDetailsReq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**2nd XML Request schema**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:brsmembersapi" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:ValidateMemberLogin>
      <login xsi:type="ns1:LoginCredentials">
        <clientAPIVersion xsi:type="xsd:int">0</clientAPIVersion>
        <username xsi:type="xsd:string">someapiusername</username>
        <password xsi:type="xsd:string">someapipassword</password>
      </login>
      <memberLogin xsi:type="ns1:MemberLoginCredentials">
        <username xsi:type="xsd:string">somememberusername</username>
        <password xsi:type="xsd:string">somememberpassword</password>
      </memberLogin>
      </ns1:ValidateMemberLogin>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

in first soap request using `<req:>` eg:-`<req:initiatePaymentDetailsReq>` in second soap request `<ns1:>` eg:-`<ns1:ValidateMemberLogin>`
what are the diffrent between them.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the namespace prefixes are different is purely cosmetic, you can choose any namespace prefix you like, as its only purpose is to act as a local abbreviation for the namespace URI.

But the fact that the two messages use different namespace URIs is extremely significant. (One uses `http://olp.bank.com/payement/service/olppaymentmanager/req`, the other uses `urn:brsmembersapi`) This means that the two messages are using completely different vocabularies defined by different people and meaning different things.

It's hard to "explain the difference" when there is no similarity - it's like asking for an explanation of the difference between archaeology and Beaujolais.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay . when 1st  SOAP request integrating with PHP code .i am facing an issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571363/how-to-create-soap-client-in-php)  . the 2nd successfully done  . I thought the reason of the  issue is <req:>